# How to write to an existing excel file in python 3.4?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, python-3.4

I want to know how I would go about writing to an existing excel file that has 3 different sheets in it. xlsxwriter only writes to new excel files it creates and xlwt isn't compatible with python 3.4. Is there a module that's similar to xlwt in the sense that it will allow me to modify my existing file? I'm using ipython 3.4 in case that helps. Is it possible to use the Pandas module to modify the file without having it delete the other sheets that aren't being used at the time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to modify it while you have Excel open you can use win32com.

PyXLL works with Python 3.4 and you can use it to write Python macros in Python, which can write back to Excel. There are also examples showing how to write Excel array functions that return pandas dataframes on github.

See https://www.pyxll.com and https://github.com/pyxll/pyxll-examples/tree/master/pandas.

If you want to try xlwt there are a few Python 3 ports around, but none of them are 'official' (e.g. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt-future/0.8.0).

Or maybe take a look at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/openpyxl/2.2.1, which can read and write Excel files.

Comment: Thank You for the all of the links, I decided to go with openpyxl as I wasn't able to get xlwt-future work with ipython.

Comment: FWIW xlwt has just been released with Python 3 support but the library is now very much in maintenance mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit Excel 2010 files on any platform with [openpyxl](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org)

Comment: Yea I went with using openpyxl as I was able to use it for both reading and writing at the same time. Before I was using pandas to read while was thinking about using xlwt to write to the file.

Comment: Pandas does support openpyxl and we're hoping to improve the integration.